# How can XmlSimple output XML just like data.to_xml?

Tags: ruby, xml-simple

Can `XmlSimple.xml_out` output XML the same way `to_xml` does? (instead of attributes, use tags):

```
> puts XmlSimple.xml_out([{'a' => 1, 'b' => 3.3}])
<opt>
  <anon a="1" b="3.3" />
</opt>

> puts ([{:a => 1, :b => 3.3}].to_xml)
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<records type="array">
  <record>
    <b type="float">3.3</b>
    <a type="integer">1</a>
  </record>
</records>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [fine manual](http://xml-simple.rubyforge.org/):

> **NoAttr => true | false (in + out) (handy)**
>   When used with xml_out, the generated XML will contain no attributes.
>   All hash key/values will be represented as nested elements instead.
>
> When used with xml_in, any attributes in the XML will be ignored.

I think you want:

```
XmlSimple.xml_out([{'a' => 1, 'b' => 3.3}], 'NoAttr' => true)
```

That should give you something closer to what `to_xml` does but you won't get the `type` attributes.